# Practical usage of the λ-calculus self-interpreter and the self-reducer?

Tags: reductions, lambda-calculus, interpreters

I came across the paper: "Efficient Self-Interpretation in Lambda Calculus" by Torben Mogensen, 1994:

http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/topps/D-128.pdf

It talks about the intepreter $E$ and the reducer Lambda Calculus forms, but after a brief reading I cannot see, what is the real usage for them. Could someone elaborate and point out what is the function of self-interpreter (also the reducer) in this text?

$$E = Y \space λe.λm.m (λx.x) (λmn.(em)(en)) (λm.λv.e(mv))$$

#### Addition

I found short notes of this topic from: 
https://crypto.stanford.edu/~blynn/lambda/#_lambda_calculus_with_lambda_calculus

> E⌈M⌉ evaluates to the normal form of M if it exists

Comment: What makes you think that something other than theoretical significance was intended?

Comment: I was about to add that "as practical as it can go". I'm not really expecting more but rather want to be sure, that I'm not missing something useful concerning Lambda Calculus.

Comment: I can't fully understand your question. Is it "how does $E$ do its job?" or "how can I call $E$ meaningfully?" or "how is having $E$ useful?". (or something else?)

Comment: I think in my case the second one would be most helpful clarification. Probably explaining it, the first one about doing its job becomes clear also and finally my ambigous initial question is answered. Thanks for putting it to other words.

Comment: The encoding of terms looks like a Church encoding of a standard algebraic type for lambda terms. Except, functions are encoded similarly to  "HOAS". (Indeed, the paper mentions HOAS for this). I'd recommend you start from the Pfenning&Elliott'98 paper mentioned in the linked PDF. Or by reading about Church encodings. If you have some experience in algebraic types in functional programming (e.g. Ocaml, Haskell), it could help.